# Disable selection of entire row when data grid cells clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to disable entire row selection when a cell clicked ?

i want to select row only if a checkbox column checked.

[image]

Comment: You can set the DataGrid.SelectionUnit property to Cell. Then either add the checkbox to the row header to make clicking it select the entire row or add the checkbox to a column and implement row selection behavior yourself. The DataGrid.SelectedCells property will hold the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the selection this way:

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid.ClearSelection(); 
}
```